# Extract part of string R

Tags: r

I have a vector of filenames and I want to extract part of the name. The vector is:

```
vect <- c("Z:/zoe/test2/H1.fusion.txt",   "Z:/zoe/test2/H1_1.fusion.txt",
"Z:/zoe/test2/H2.fusion.txt",  "Z:/zoe/test2/H3.fusion.txt",
"Z:/zoe/test2/H4.fusion.txt",   "Z:/zoe/test2/H5.fusion.txt")
```

I would like to loop through the vector and extract the `H` part of the name so in between the third `/` and the first `.`
Ideally I don't want to count the amount of characters for substring as the directory names and file names would change.
Also as there are more than one `/` and `.`, I can't use `s.indexOf`?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `basename` (no packages needed):

```
# > basename(vect)
# [1] "H1.fusion.txt"   "H1_1.fusion.txt" "H2.fusion.txt"   "H3.fusion.txt"  
# [5] "H4.fusion.txt"   "H5.fusion.txt"

gsub("[.].+$", "", basename(vect))

# [1] "H1"   "H1_1" "H2"   "H3"   "H4"   "H5"
```

If you're wondering, `dirname()` gives you the directory name:

```
# > dirname(vect)
# [1] "Z:/zoe/test2" "Z:/zoe/test2" "Z:/zoe/test2" "Z:/zoe/test2" "Z:/zoe/test2"
# [6] "Z:/zoe/test2"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `pathological` package and then go:

```
library(pathological)
vect

# [1] "Z:/zoe/test2/H1.fusion.txt"   "Z:/zoe/test2/H1_1.fusion.txt"
# [3] "Z:/zoe/test2/H2.fusion.txt"   "Z:/zoe/test2/H3.fusion.txt"  
# [5] "Z:/zoe/test2/H4.fusion.txt"   "Z:/zoe/test2/H5.fusion.txt"  

decompose_path(vect)$filename
# [1] "H1"   "H1_1" "H2"   "H3"   "H4"   "H5"
```

Which I think is what you want.

And it has the advantage of properly handling file paths on different systems. `decompose_path` handily chops paths up into parts:

```
> decompose_path(vect)
                                  dirname filename  extension
Z:/zoe/test2/H1.fusion.txt   Z:/zoe/test2       H1 fusion.txt
Z:/zoe/test2/H1_1.fusion.txt Z:/zoe/test2     H1_1 fusion.txt
Z:/zoe/test2/H2.fusion.txt   Z:/zoe/test2       H2 fusion.txt
Z:/zoe/test2/H3.fusion.txt   Z:/zoe/test2       H3 fusion.txt
Z:/zoe/test2/H4.fusion.txt   Z:/zoe/test2       H4 fusion.txt
Z:/zoe/test2/H5.fusion.txt   Z:/zoe/test2       H5 fusion.txt
```

And it will also work if your paths are separated by backslashes, which are also valid separators in Windows systems.

```
> v2
[1] "Z:\\zoe\\test2\\H1.fusion.txt"   "Z:\\zoe\\test2\\H1_1.fusion.txt"
[3] "Z:\\zoe\\test2\\H2.fusion.txt"   "Z:\\zoe\\test2\\H3.fusion.txt"  
[5] "Z:\\zoe\\test2\\H4.fusion.txt"   "Z:\\zoe\\test2\\H5.fusion.txt"  
> decompose_path(v2)$filename
[1] "H1"   "H1_1" "H2"   "H3"   "H4"   "H5"  
>
```

If you have paths, try and treat them like paths and not general strings - the `pathological` package is a big help and worth using.

Comment: Interesting! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions are quite useful for such simple text extraction tasks. In this case, the idea is first to match the longest string possible that is still followed by a slash, some non-period characters, a period, and then anything. Then, return what happens when we replace everything described with the non-period parts identified above.

```
 gsub(".*/([^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", vect)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub("(^/)|(\\.$)", "", regmatches(vect, regexpr("/([^\\.|/)])+\\.", vect)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(vec, "[H0-9_]+.[a-z]+")
```

> ```
>  [1] "H1.fusion"   "H1_1.fusion" "H2.fusion"   "H3.fusion"   "H4.fusion"   "H5.fusion"
> ```

Or if you don't want the "fusion" part:

```
str_extract("[H][0-9_]+")
```

> ```
>  [1] "H1"   "H1_1" "H2"   "H3"   "H4"   "H5"
> ```